# Laravel Blade view calling static property and namespace

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-blade

I have been working in Facebook Ad SDK which works well in the controller because it has full PHP syntax support.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;

class AdController extends Controller
{ 
    private $access_token = '';
    private $account_id = '';
    private $app_secret = '';
    private $app_id = '';

    public function __construct(){
        Api::init($this->app_id, $this->app_secret, $this->access_token);
     }


    public  function index()
    {

        $account = new AdAccount($this->account_id);

        $params = array(
            'time_interval' => array(
                'day_start' => array('year' =>'2013', 'month'=> '5', 'day'=>'1'),
                'day_stop' => array( 'year'=>'2017', 'month'=>'12', 'day'=>'31')
            ),
            'limit' => 500,
        );
        $fields = array(
            CampaignFields::NAME,
            CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
            CampaignFields::STATUS,
        );

        $campaigns = $account->getCampaigns($fields,$params);
/*
        return view('admin.campaigns.index', [
            'campaigns' => $campaigns
        ]);

*/




        foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
            //echo "campaign ID". . "<br/>";
            echo "<a href='ad_detail.php?id=".$campaign->{CampaignFields::ID}."'>".$campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}."</a><br/>";



        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to pass the $campaigns in the view like this way, though I knew it would not work because of the absence of namespaces and conflict between blade {{ }} and $campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}/$campaign->{CampaignFields::ID}.

```
@foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {

            <a href='ad_detail.php?id="{{$campaign->{CampaignFields::ID}}}"'>" {{$campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}}}"</a>

@endforeach
```

My question is how to pass the $campaigns array in the view with proper blade syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the field from within the control as a string and then reference it inside blade like so:

controller.php

```
 return view('index', ['campaigns' => $campaigns, 'properties' => $fields]);
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {

    <a href='ad_detail.php?id="{{ $campaign->{$properties[0]} }}"'>
        "{{ $campaign->{properties[1]} }}"
    </a>

@endforeach
```